# Swift: What is the proper implementation to construct an object that will handle JSON/Dictionalry parsing

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I've managed to get very confused with regard to Swift Codeable, struct vs. class, and JSON parsing.

I am trying to manage data for various bundles of images, of which multiple bundles can be assigned to a given `slate`.  I want to be able to append additional image bundles to a `slate` if it already exists.

The JSON format would look something like:

```
{
 slate: "S1A:,
 imageBundles: [
      {
       timestamp: "2019-10-11_23:00",
       fileUrls: [
            "files/R0010514.JPG",
            "files/R0010515.JPG",
            "files/R0010516.JPG"
            ]
      },
      {
       timestamp: "2019-10-12_02:30",
       fileUrls: [
            "files/R0010525.JPG",
            "files/R0010526.JPG",
            "files/R0010527.JPG"
            ]
      }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to create `struct` objects to work within Swift:

```
struct ImageBundle: Codable {
    var timestamp: String?
    var fileUrls: [String]?
}

struct SlateBundle: Codable {
    var slate: String?
    var imageBundles: [ImageBundle]! = []
}
```

This does seem to build an object with the information assigned, however I'm not sure how to make proper use of this within the code.

I cannot seem to create a new `ImageBundle()` and append that to `mySlateBundle["S1A"]`  Or have a new `SlateBundle()` created if I try to assign `mySlateBundle["newSlateName"]`

Clearly I'm missing some very basic procedure, or more than likely mixing my understanding of the various object types.

In order to try and be more clear...  How would I declare/assign the `struct` objects for given the JSON structure of:

```
{
 city: "Los Angeles",
 neighborhoods: [
  {
   name: "venice",
   streets: [
        "Main Street",
        "Abbot Kinney",
        "Pacific"
        ]
  },
  {
   name: "Hollywood",
   streets: [
        "Sunset Blvd",
        "La Brea Blvd",
        "Highland Ave"
        ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: "I cannot seem to create a new `ImageBundle()` and append that to `mySlateBundle["S1A"]`" What is the code that you used and what error does it give?

Comment: Don't use IUO types(`T!`) anywhere except `@IBOutlet` variables. Your property is obviously non-optional, just use `[ImageBundle]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will create the same structure you have in your json.

```
var slate = SlateBundle(slate: "S1A")

slate.imageBundles.append(ImageBundle(timestamp: "2019-10-11_23:00", 
                                    fileUrls: ["files/R0010514.JPG", "files/R0010515.JPG", "files/R0010516.JPG"]))
slate.imageBundles.append(ImageBundle(timestamp: "2019-10-12_02:30", 
                                    fileUrls: ["files/R0010525.JPG", "files/R0010526.JPG", "files/R0010527.JPG"]))
```

you could also create a simple function in SlateBundle to somewhat simplify the code

```
mutating func add(imageBundle bundle: ImageBundle) {
    self.imageBundles.append(bundle)
}
```

and then the bundles are added as

```
slate.add(imageBundle: ImageBundle(timestamp: "2019-10-11_23:00", 
                                   fileUrls: ["files/R0010514.JPG", "files/R0010515.JPG", "files/R0010516.JPG"]))
slate.add(imageBundle: ImageBundle(timestamp: "2019-10-12_02:30", 
                                   fileUrls: ["files/R0010525.JPG", "files/R0010526.JPG", "files/R0010527.JPG"]))
```

Comment: This will definitely work, although just accessing `slate.imageBundles.append(someNewImageBundle)` is easier and cleaner imo. But then there's still the issue that if you then add this slate to a dictionary and then want to modify it you need to be careful to modify the value in the dictionary itself and not a copy of it

Comment: Thank you.  Given this approach, if I needed to add a new ImageBundle to ```slate["S1A"]``` how would I go about that?  I guess I essentially need a dictionary of `SlateBundle` objects?

Comment: @P-Rod I don't really understand. If you need to add a new ImageBundle to an existing SlateBundle then why would you need a dictionary. You could use a dictionary if you have multiple SlateBundle instances of course.

Answer (score 0):

The `Codable` structs are good the way they are, I think your issue might be related to object and value types in Swift. structs are value types so then when you try to do something like

```swift
let slate = mySlateBundle["S1A"]
slate.imageBundles.append(someOtherBundle)
```

it will not reflect these changes in the dictionary of slates. What you could do instead is this:

```swift
mySlateBundle["S1A"].append(someOtherBundle)
```

Comment: `slate` is an instance of a struct, not a dictionary

Comment: I never said that. I meant that since `SlateBundle` is a struct you basically make a separate copy of if when creating a reference to it

Comment: When I try: var slateBundles = [String : [ImageBundle]]() and then attempt: slateBundles["S1A"].append(anImageBundle) I get an error: Value of type '[ImageBundle]?' has no member 'append'

Comment: I was under the impression that `slateBundles` had the type `[String: SlateBundle]`

Comment: In my effort to pair down the code for easier reading I may have furthered the confusion.  Perhaps it is best to think of these in terms of `Cities` (SlateBundle) and `Neighborhoods` (ImageBundle).  I essentially want to add a new city to my dataset and occasionally add another neighborhood, which includes a collection of streets among other metadata.